# Using Chebychev's Inequality to find a lower bound

Tags: probability

A fair coin is flipped 100 times. Find the lower bound, based on Chebyshev's bound, on the probability of the event that the number of heads observed is in {45,46,..,55}. Compare this to the exact probability 0.73.

So n = 100. p = 0.5. E(X) = 50. Standard deviation = sqrt(100*.5*.5) = 5

45 - 55 is within 1 standard deviation of the mean 50. So I get that k = 1, 1 - 1/k = 1 - 1/1 = 0.

P(|X-E(X)| < 5) = P(|X-E(X)| < 5σ/5) = P(|X-E(X)| < σ)

Then flip it around so we're looking at things outside of 45-55.

P(|X-E(X)| > σ) <= σ^2/σ^2
P(|X-E(X)| > σ) <= 1

How is this useful. I don't get how to use Chebyshev's when k = 1. Isn't this just telling me the probability is <= 1?

Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chebyshev Inequality does not necessarily give **good** bounds!

However, the Inequality was slightly misused. I believe it says that the probability that $|X-\mu| \ge k\sigma$ is $\le \frac{1}{k^2}$. In our case, we are interested in $k\sigma=6$.

Comment: One day I will learn the difference between $<$ and $\le$...

Comment: Thanks for your response. How are you getting that kσ=6? Isn't k=1? and σ=5? Sorry, I really don't understand what the solution to this should be. And I'm also not sure about the second part of the question (compare this to the exact probability .73)

Comment: @user2503227 The inequalities here are strict. It is not true that $55-50<5$. You need to allow $6$ heads either way to fit in your range of $45$ to $55$.

Comment: @user2503227: First look at the Chebyshev Inequality as I wrote it. If we are **not** in the range $45$ to $55$ (inclusive, that's what your problem says) then we are $56$ or bigger, or $44$ or smaller. So $|X-\mu|\ge 6$. It is true that if your problem had said $46$ to $54$, then we would get $k=1$, totally useless. And if it had said $47$ to $53$, we would have $k\lt 1$, ridiculously useless.